# Running DRI_PRIME Command By Using Python Subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, subprocess

I need to run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo` command by using Python subprocess also it should not cause shell injection risk.

It gives the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DRI_PRIME=1'
```

Code:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["DRI_PRIME=1", "glxinfo"], shell=False).decode()
print(output)

System: Python3, OS: Linux
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is solved by using the following code:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["env", "DRI_PRIME=1", "glxinfo"], shell=False).decode()
```

A short explanation from manual page of `env`:

```
env - run a program in a modified environment
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for how to run a command with a modified environment.

```python
import os
import subprocess

env = os.environ.copy()
env['DRI_PRIME'] = '1'
p = subprocess.run(['glxinfo'], env=env, capture_output=True)
print(p.stdout)
```